# namenode does not come up with hadoop YARN

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using hadoop YARN on ubuntu.  I have setup the hadoop directory (as well as datanode and namenode directories) in the /usr/local directories.  Whenever I run start-dfs.sh, the namenode does not come up - the message in the screen output complains about missing bin/hdfs file even though the file is there (with read/write access).  I have setup bashrc with Hadoop environment variables (copied below).  Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL  ##added because I was not sure about the line below
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

Comment: Are you running start-dfs.sh as the user who owns the hadoop install directory?

Comment: yes - I created a hduser and ran chown on the directory for the hduser (I verified using ls -ltr).  Then I run start-dfs.sh using the hduser account (I am using hadoop-2.5.1)

Comment: I run both start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh.  Only resourcemanager comes up (in jps) and is accessible through the browser.  The namenode never comes up and I do not see any exceptions in the logs - just the printout when I run the start-dfs.sh that it cannot find $HADOOP_INSTALL/bin/hdfs.  $HADOOP_INSTALL points to the hadoop directory where I have the bin/hdfs.

Comment: Did you try to format the namenode ?

Comment: yes I did - that was not the issue.  Something is amiss in my bashrc file and the start-dfs script does not work for me.  The individual scripts run fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try running namenode with the following (as opposed to using the start-dfs.sh) and see if that works.  

        hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
        hadoop-daemon.sh start secondarynamenode
        hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
        hadoop-daemon.sh start nodemanager
        mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
```